# How to pass a data from a link and then print it in a controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a data from a link and then print it in a controller.
This is my View:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("Main_controller/show_chronicles/".$row->chronicles_no); ?>">Chronicles</a>
```

and this is my controller function:

```
function show_chronicles()
{
  echo $row->chronicles_no;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update your function:**

```
function show_chronicles($chronicles_no)
{
  echo $chronicles_no;
}
```

Comment: @TimBrownlaw No need of calling same. Because its an already  value and which will directly assign to variable which we added

Comment: @DeadManAlive Ok yep you are right.